# ANDROID - FIREBASE - Serializing Collections is not supported

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, serialization, realm

I'm using realm db and firebase realtime database to build my application. Basically, I've a farm and when I create this farm, I can upload it to firebase, but when I'm trying to update it, I have the following error: Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead

Basically, I'm doing the update when user closes the app, so I'll insert my class code and my onStop code. If you know what I can do to fix, please, help me. I'm desperate. lol

This is my onStop code:

```
  override fun onStop() {
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    realm.beginTransaction()
    val farm : Farm = realm.where<Farm>().contains("id", id).findFirst()!!
    farm.saveToDb()
    realm.commitTransaction()
    super.onStop()
}
```

This is my farm code:

```
open class Farm(
var codigoFazenda: String = "",
var programa: String = "",
var senha: String = "",
var id: String = ""
) : RealmObject() {

var area = 0.0
var metaMargemLiquida = 0.0
var metaMargemBruta = 0.0
var metaRendaBruta = 0.0
var metaPatrimonioLiquido = 0.0
var metaLucro = 0.0
var metasaldo = 0.0
var metaLiquidezGeral = 0.0
var metaLiquidezCorrente = 0.0
var observacao: String = ""
var modificacao: String = ""

  fun myEquals(farm: Farm) : Boolean {
    if(codigoFazenda == farm.codigoFazenda
        && programa== farm.programa
        && senha== farm.senha
        && id== farm.id
        && area== farm.area
        && metaMargemLiquida== farm.metaMargemLiquida
        && metaMargemBruta== farm.metaMargemBruta
        && metaRendaBruta== farm.metaRendaBruta
        && metaPatrimonioLiquido == farm.metaPatrimonioLiquido
        && metaLucro == farm.metaLucro
        && metasaldo == metasaldo
        && metaLiquidezGeral == farm.metaLiquidezGeral
        && metaLiquidezCorrente == farm.metaLiquidezCorrente
        && observacao== farm.observacao
    ) {
        return true
    }
        return false
  }

  @Exclude
  fun attModificacao() {
      val todayDate: Date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
      modificacao = todayDate.time.toString()
  }

  @Exclude
  fun saveToDb() {
      attModificacao()
      val db = Firebase.database.reference.child("fazendas").child(programa).child(id)
    db.setValue(this)
  }
}
```

Since I'm using realmObject, I can't use a data class, so I've created this MyEquals method to compare my results. This attModificacao is my updateMethod, I call this to save my last update time to firebase and my save to db pushes the value to firebase.